# Hide UI for activity, but only when launched via intent

Tags: android, user-interface, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to write an Android app which controls an external device via http commands.

When the app is launched normally from the icon on the homescreen, it goes into a full UI allowing the user to interact with the app and control the equipment.  That's all fine.

I now want to add support for Android intents, so that other programs (e.g. Tasker) can issue commands to my app.  However, when the app receives an intent, I don't want the UI to display.  I want everything to run in the background to execute the command contained in the intent.

All of the methods/data etc that my app uses are in the main activity, so I would like both to have the full UI and the handling of intents in that activity.

In the onCreate method, I therefore check to see whether the app has been launched normally or via an intent.

If launched normally, it goes on to call setContentView(R.layout.main) etc to bring up the UI.

If launched via the intent, I try to call setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoDisplay) to try to hide the UI completely, but I still get a black screen with the title bar at the top.

Is there any way to suppress an activity's UI, but only when it has been launched by an intent please?

Any help gratefully received.  I can see other questions that address hiding the UI, but they all recommend changing a setting in the Android Manifest, whereas what I want to do is conditional on how the app was launched.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to suppress an activity's UI, but only when it has been launched by an intent please?

Create a subclass of your main activity that sets its no-UI theme in the manifest. Give that activity the unique `<intent-filter>` that is to be used by third-party apps. This way, your logic stays in one class, yet you get your no-UI theme applied for the third-party apps.

IOW, if you are waiting until Java code to make this decision, you're too late.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  I've if understood correctly, you mean I need to create a new separate activity class, which inherits everything from the existing one, which is dedicated to handling the intent and which has no UI.  Does that mean that the new activity handling the intent will run completely independently of the main activity (UI) with its own independent data and I don't have to worry about them interfering with each other?

Comment: Actually, I think I've sorted it as per your suggestion above. Now working. Thank you.